VisionOS navigation link, customise the radius
Is there any way to reduce the radius of this navigation link in vision os?
Is not a button is a link, I tried using .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle(radius: 10)) as suggest in other post but does not work.
I would like somthing like the following shape, I try few option but no one work.

struct DetailsPlalistView: View {
    @Binding var mode: stateMode
    var playlist: PlayListModel
    var reader: GeometryProxy
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            modeIcon
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .padding()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Text(playlist.playlistName)
                .font(.headline)
                
        }
            .frame(width: reader.size.width/4 , height: reader.size.height/4)
            .buttonBorderShape(.roundedRectangle(radius: 0))
    }
    
    private var modeIcon: Image {
        switch mode {
        case .deleteMode:
            return Image(systemName: "trash.circle.fill")
        case .updateMode:
            return Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise.circle.fill")
        case .normalMode:
            return Image(systemName: "tv")
        }
    }
}


used in a navigationLink:
ScrollView {
                        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(playlists) { playlist in
                                NavigationLink(value: playlist, label: {
                                    DetailsPlalistView(mode: $mode, playlist: playlist, reader: reader)
                                   
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }



See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78615536/5133585

I saw the post but it work only on the button, if applied on navigation link does't work

Really? Where did you put it? There isn't even a NavigationLink in the code you included in the question.

Ops Sorry I found solution was applied in a wrong place. Thanks a lot !
